# SVN Export Removed Folders

Tags: svn, export

I am on Ubunutu 12.04.1 LTS and I am using RabbitVCS for SVN version control. I had a working copy folder named "Work_proj" inside of a directory named swdev. So:

~/swdev/Work_proj

I also had other folders in the swdev folder. Inside of Work_proj was a folder named "source":

~/swdev/Work_proj/source

I tried to copy and paste the source folder into the swdev folder and then remove it from version control. To do this, I tried running svn export with ~/swdev/source as the the source and ~/swdev as the destination, thinking this would remove it from version control. Instead, the entire ~/swdev folder and all of its subfolder seemed to have just disappeared. What happened and is there anyway that I can retrieve these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you had booked everything in, then I think you may be able to just relocate it or check it out elsewhere.

Export, should not remove the actual source, just the versioning (on the exported version), i.e. you only end up with the latest.

Comment: It completed removed the ~/swdev folder and everything in it. ~/swdev/Work_proj had uncommitted changes.

Comment: That is rough. Are you sure it is not still in the hidden folders under the swdev folder. Svn has a mad amount of hidden folders managing state.

Comment: It completed removed the entire ~/swdev folder, not just its contents.